# What is the difference between angular.copy() and an assignment (=)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to assign some values when a button click event happens via event parameter:

```
$scope.update = function(context) {
    $scope.master = context;
};
```

I have assigned `user` values to  `$scope.master`.

Now i am seeing [angular.copy()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy). So I wrote the code with [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy).

```
$scope.update = function(context) {
    $scope.master = angular.copy(context)
};
```

Both are doing same, so what is the difference? Please tell me about the difference between `angular.copy()` and `equal(=)`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `angular.copy()` performs a deep copy, whereas `=` just assigns the variable to the same memory address, so the result of `angular.copy()` will always be a new object that you can modify safely without modifying the original object.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As can be [read here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) `angular.copy()` performs a deep copy (cf. "clone") of the argument - essentially creating a new object - whereas using the assignment operator `=` just assigns *reference*'s.

Thus in the latter case, if you we're to change something in `$scope.master` you would also change `context`.

Cheers,

Comment: How would "="  differ from angular.extend(). Can you please explain

Answer (score 11):

`=` represents a reference whereas `angular.copy()` creates a new object as a deep copy.

Using `=` would mean that changing a property of `context`would change the corresponding property of `$scope.master` or vice versa.

Using `angular.copy()` the two objects would remain seperate and changes would not reflect on each other.

Answer (score 3):

When you manipulate primitive types (like int) in Javascript, `=` and `angular.copy` are the same as any assignment results in copying the value of the variable.

When you manipulate objects in Javascript, `=` assign a reference to the existing object to the variable and `angular.copy` is copying, that means creating a new object with the same properties and values and assigning the new object's reference to the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Simply

`angular.copy()` is same as `.clone()` of jquery which create & returns same object copy with dept. (call by value)

`=` it does assign the value with its reference value(call by reference),

`a = b` in this a will be `b` value is  assigned to `a`, but if both `a` & `b` are array then changes in `a` will reflect in `b` & vice versa.

Comment: Call-by-value and call-by-reference are different concepts related to method calls. This is about assignments and object creation. You shouldn't confuse the two things.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup could i know why it would be considered as same as like oops?

Answer (score 0):

In assignment we share the reference of the object. when we use angular.copy we create a new reference point with the same object details.

```
var user1={name:'hello'};
```

The object `{name:'hello'}` has a reference point(let's say 123, which is saved in user1;
when we write

```
var user2=var user1; //reference point of user2 is also 123 
user2.name="world"; //we update the object in 123
console.log(user1.name); //answer is "world" because reference object is updated
```

In case you don't want to update user1 when you change something in user2 we have to create a copy.
we can do it like

```
var user2=angular.copy(user1);
```

or

```
var user2=Object.assign({},user1);
```