# AngularJS is cross-binding variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-bindings

I begin my Angular controller by downloading JSON data using Promises and storing it in variables:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', function($scope, $http, $q) {
  var req1 = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'link to JSON 1', cache: 'true'});
  var req2 = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'link to JSON 2', cache: 'true'});

  $q.all([req1, req2]).then(function(response){
    var res1 = response[0].data;
    var res2 = response[1].data;

    $scope.data1 = res1;       // JSON which I will manipulate
    $scope.data1Ref = res1;   // JSON for reference which I won't manipulate

    $scope.data2 = res2;
    $scope.data2Ref = res2;

    init(); // do the stuff with the data
  });
}]);
```

After `init()` is done however, if I check `$scope.data1` and `$scope.data1Ref` they both have been modified, that is they're bound together.

Why is this happening and how can I make sure to keep a stored version of the original downloaded JSON for reference?

Comment: It's because $scope.data1 and $scope.data1Ref reference res1 so any changes to res1 will be reflected in those two. You need to make a copy of res1 before assigning it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749433/difference-between-angular-copy-and-assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference. When you set $scope.data1 and $scope.data1Ref equal to res1, you are setting them equal to a *reference* to res1.

To get around this, you can make a deep copy of your res objects using [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy).

`$scope.res1Ref = angular.copy(res1);`

Comment: Interesting that `angular.copy()` seems to take considerable amount of time to run (almost 4000ms in this case), more than downloading the JSON again. So potentially a workaround, at least in this case, would be downloading the JSON twice.

Comment: Someone else with this issue has found a faster cloning algorithm: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11099

Also, lodash has a deep clone function that you could try, _.cloneDeep() https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep

Comment: Thank you a lot for this, paulgoblin. Using the code from https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11099 has caused a significant improve in performance.

Answer (score 0):

When you use assignment for objects, you are only giving the variable a reference to the object, not copying the object. In your code, `$scope.data1`, `$scope.data1Ref`, and `res1` are all pointing to the exact same object instance. To make a new object you need to copy the existing object.

Angular provides two functions which can copy an object, one creates a shallow copy, and the other a deep copy. A shallow copy copies primitive fields and if the object contains child objects, then the original and the copy both point to the same child object instance. In a deep copy, any child objects have new copies created also.

`angular.extend` can be used to create a shallow copy, while `angular.copy` does a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS, complex objects are passed by reference. You can find more info here: [Difference between angular.copy() and assignment (=)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749433/difference-between-angular-copy-and-assignment)