# How to use ng-repeat to show all the values coming from the API in which I need to show only one key value from all the objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Through my API I am having two or more objects. In objects there are different. Different key values like `id`, `name`, `account` etc. But I need to show only ids of all the objects, in select box.

I am using `ng-repeat` like this in my HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selectedid" class="form-control"> 
  <option ng-repeat="id in editIdOptionsData" value="{{id}}">{{id}}</option> 
</select>
```

And for the response I am doing :

```
deal.getIdData($scope.accountDetail.accountUsers[0].role, $scope.accountDetail.id)
.then(function successCb(data){ 
  $scope.editIdOptionsData=data; 
});
```

But like this in my select box I am getting all the objects. Can you tell me how to fetch only `id` from all the object in which one value is selected by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're doing is setting whole object into option

```
<select ng-model="selectedid" class="form-control"> 
  <option ng-repeat="id in editIdOptionsData" value="{{id}}">{{id}}</option> 
</select>
```

the 'id' in your code is one whole object. What you should do is:

```
<option ng-repeat="id in editIdOptionsData" value="{{id.id}}">{{id.id}}</option>
```

Or just for readability

```
<option ng-repeat="element in editIdOptionsData" value="{{element.id}}">{{element.id}}</option>
```

EDIT 1:
If you want to select one of the option based on some condition you can use ngSelected directive:

```
ng-selected="<your condition>"
```

in your example it will be something like that (if I understand correctly your need)

```
<select ng-model="selectedid" class="form-control"> 
  <option ng-selected="selectedid == id.id" ng-repeat="id in editIdOptionsData" value="{{id.id}}">{{id.id}}</option> 
</select>
```

If that's not what your looking you have to be more specific in your questions.

Comment: Thank you Daniel.. It is working.. But I need to show some selected id then how can I show that.

Comment: ngSelected directive can help you. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Proper approach is use `ng-options` and `ng-model`. Note that `ng-model` should always always be an object

Comment: Actually after adding "$scope.selectedid = $scope.editIdOptionsData[0].id; " in my controller with ngSelected directive it is working .. But while save on a button click it is not getting saved..

Comment: I am writing for saving like "$scope.dealDetail.decisionMakerDetail.email = $scope.selectedid" because of "dealDetail.decisionMakerDetail.email" value is also coming through ng-bind.

Comment: I would add ng-click="save(id.id)" on option element and in $scope.save(id) method in controller do $scope.selectedid = id

Comment: Maybe you're not setting $scope.selectedid on clicking your save method

Comment: I saw some example using angular.copy. Is it needed to use that ?

Comment: No. Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749433/difference-between-angular-copy-and-assignment

Comment: What should I add in this for saving my value ? $scope.updateDealDetail = function updateDealDetail (){
      $scope.showEditView = !$scope.showEditView;
      $scope.dealDetail.decisionMakerDetail.email = $scope.selectedid;
   }<button ng-click="updateDealDetail(eoid.email)" ng-disabled="dealDataSaveButtonDisabled">Update</button>

Comment: Why are you invoking updateDealDetail method in ng-click with a parameter? You're not using it in body of that method. Are you sure everything there is ok? And answering your question: You should set $scope.selectedid to the id of option user chose

Comment: No I am not sure whether I should pass those parameter or not.. And for default selected option I used "$scope.selectedid = $scope.editIdOptionsData[0].id;" What is going wrong with this is that each and everytime on selection it is having the first value only. I guess That's why  I am unable to save my value. Can you please tell me what should I do in this now..:(

Comment: I would recommend you to pass chosen id as parameter and then assign it to selectedid in save method. Also if you save chosen option in database  you could try to assign it to selectedid when opening the page and if it is null then set default as you are doing now

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedid" ng-options="object as object.id in object for editIdOptionsData" class="form-control"> </select>
```