# How to set the value property in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

Html Code

```
    <select   class="form-control" id="txtcity" data-ng-model="Register.city" ng-options="item for item in dtcmbCity">
                                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                    </select>
<button type="button" ng-click="btnSet();">Set Item</button>
```

Js Code

```
$scope.Register = {city: ''};
$scope.dtcmbCity = ['Delhi','Bombay','Chennai'];

 $scope.btnSet= function () {
        $scope.Register.city = "Delhi"        
    }
```

My problem is when load the form the data (delhi,bombay,chennai) displayed in the select box. and then i click the set button i want to set delhi into the selection box.

thanks please help

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762855/how-to-use-ng-repeat-to-show-all-the-values-coming-from-the-api-in-which-i-need/37763050#37763050

Comment: friend, your code works fine as you described. see [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UwUBg8HdROhH4F5DjHq9)

Comment: Whats is the exact ask here ?? the code seems to be doing what you are looking for.

Comment: Please read [ask] and put more effort into explaining what your exact problem is. Your trivial example works just as you describe it

Comment: @JossefHarush friend i just edit your code. can you please check this code. it that you can find my issue... https://plnkr.co/edit/5QqqXpQ27ga62Lr7tcbA?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl please check this link https://plnkr.co/edit/5QqqXpQ27ga62Lr7tcbA?p=preview

Comment: item not set.. please help

Comment: The ajax doesn't load data in that demo. Look at demo above that works fine

Comment: click F12 and see in server response `PIN Code Does Not Exist` https://plnkr.co/edit/Da4r5kE6ZEAtmCc1vHY9?p=preview

Comment: @JossefHarush Nono you please see this code  https://plnkr.co/edit/5QqqXpQ27ga62Lr7tcbA?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl https://plnkr.co/edit/5QqqXpQ27ga62Lr7tcbA?p=preview

Comment: Stop posting the same link over and over without any updates. `$scope.Register.pin` is undefined so there is nothing being populated in the `select`. You can't set `ng-model` for item that doesn't exist

Comment: I suspect your problem is the data from api is different structure than the simple array shown in question. Show actual response data structure as per [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl i am new in web app. so sorry for the inconvenience. here i click the get button i can view the data. can u please check once again. https://plnkr.co/edit/VoXeny3dgtPaYNGAWNR8?p=preview

Comment: change `track by item.Address` to `track by Address` and it works fine. You oversimplified the question code and it wasn't representative of your real issue. Also note that API is adding extra whitespace to some `Address` values

Comment: @charlietfl sir i just change track by item.Address to track by Address .. but this code is not working  $scope.Register.city = "Kolenchery";

Comment: Works fine here after click Get then Set https://plnkr.co/edit/1frcWycu2cnDZBbMAZ8A?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl . click set item combo shows  kadayiruppu i set as kolenchery..

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for the great support sir. the problem is data from api is different structure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking for setting the value attribute in the options fields same as the text value than this can help you.

Your current code .

```
ng-options="item for item in dtcmbCity"
```

Result HTML.

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="txtcity"  data-ng-model="Register.city" ng-options="item for item in dtcmbCity">

<option value="" class="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
<option label="Delhi" value="string:Delhi">Delhi</option>
<option label="Bombay" value="string:Bombay">Bombay</option>
<option label="Chennai" value="string:Chennai">Chennai</option>
</select>
```

if you use the track by in ng-options , html code is

```
ng-options="item for item in dtcmbCity track by item"
```

Result HTML.

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="txtcity" data-ng-model="Register.city" ng-options="item for item in dtcmbCity track by item">
<option value="" class="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
<option label="Delhi" value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
<option label="Bombay" value="Bombay">Bombay</option>
<option label="Chennai" value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
</select>
```

Setting the value on button click is working fine.

Comment: Yeah, even the code written by Vinod is also fine. Just tried to let him know the way if he was looking for something like this as the ask was not clear.

Comment: this is happening because your binding the item object in the select. you will have to set it by setting the object itself in the ng-model. Check the belo plunker. Hope it will help. https://plnkr.co/edit/DtnnV8QgBuE7MydYHYtg?p=preview