# Angularjs add new data to array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework

I want to add the new data into the array variable, but the thing is, the new data is inserted it to overwrite existing data already exist.
I need to fix?

HTML Code:

```
<ion-view title="แจ้งสัตว์เกิด" id="page4">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <form id="page4-form3" class="list">
      <label class="item item-select" id="page4-select5">
        <span class="input-label">ประเภท</span>
        <select name="selectCategory" id="selectCategory" ng-model="form.categoryID" ng-change="getType(form.categoryID)">
          <option ng-repeat="recordCategory in myDataArrayCategory" value="{{recordCategory.aCategory}}">{{recordCategory.aCategoryName}}</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-select" id="page4-select6">
        <span class="input-label">ชนิด</span>
        <select name="selectType" id="selectType" ng-model="form.typeID">
          <option ng-repeat="recordType in myDataArrayType"  value="{{recordType.aType}}">{{recordType.aTypeName}}</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input" id="page4-input5">
        <span class="input-label">จำนวน</span>
        <input type="number" ng-model="form.Amount" placeholder="">
      </label>
    </form>
    <button id="page4-button2" class="button button-positive button-block" ng-click="addData(form)">เพิ่ม</button>
    <ion-list id="page4-list3">
      <ion-item id="page4-list-item4">Item</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button id="page4-button3" class="button button-positive button-block">บันทึก</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

JS Code:

```
angular.module('starter')

.controller('addDataCtrl',function ($scope,$http) {

  $scope.form = {
    categoryID:'',
    typeID:'',
    Amount:''
  };

  $scope.arrData = [];

  $scope.addData = function (arrInput) {
    $scope.arrData.push(arrInput);
    console.log($scope.arrData);
  }
});
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MtBx.png

I have to fix it?
Do I need to do to add new data into variables Array won't overwrite the original.

Comment: Are you trying to empty the existing array and push the new data? Could you please fix your grammar and make it understandable.

Comment: I create a variable Array up 1. When the button is pressed to put your values are put up in the Array.

Comment: Can not understand neither your question nor your comment. Please be specific

Comment: can you put your example in jsdfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original value is getting overwritten due to shallow copy of the array .Actually when we use '=' for assignment, the new variable and old variable refers to the same memory location , hence if you modify one the value of other will also get modified .

Solution for this - use deep copy using angular.copy(source,destination) as below -

```
$scope.addData = function (arrInput) {
var deepCopy= {};
angular.copy(arrInput, deepCopy);
$scope.arrData.push(deepCopy);
console.log($scope.arrData);}
```

Please check this [copy-and-assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749433/difference-between-angular-copy-and-assignment) link for more details.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me 
I can do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a deep copy of the object because arrInput is passed to $scope.addData by reference!! Change $scope.addData to:

```
  $scope.addData = function (arrInput) {
    var tempObject = {};
    angular.copy(arrInput, tempObject);
    $scope.arrData.push(tempObject);
    console.log($scope.arrData);
  }
```

Here is an example that I simplified: https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/occysaa1/

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me 
I can do it