# What is the difference between angular.copy() and Object.assign()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, copy, clone

I would like to know if there are any differences.

I can see that `Object.assign()` just clones the object, and doing so, no matter if I change the original object, the cloned object will maintain its values.

Nevertheless, I see that functions are not copied, only enumerable properties.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.obj1 = {
    prop1: () => "a string",
    prop2: [1, 2, 3],
    prop3: new Date(),
    prop4: {
      a: 1
    }
  };
  $scope.obj2 = {
    "$scope.obj1": $scope.obj1,
   "angular.copy Obj1": angular.copy($scope.obj1)
};

$scope.angularClone = angular.copy($scope.obj1);
$scope.es6clone = Object.assign({}, $scope.obj1) ;
$scope.obj1.prop2= "newProp2"
$scope.obj1 = "destroyed obj1";

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h3>obj1</h3> {{obj1}}
    <hr>
    <h3>obj2</h3> {{obj2}}
    <hr>
    <h3>angularClone</h3> {{angularClone}}
    <hr>
    <h3>es6clone</h3> {{es6clone}}
    <hr>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749433/difference-between-angular-copy-and-assignment

Comment: I've seen it, but in the snippet you can see that the behavior is different than a plain assignment

Answer (score 2):

So the main difference is that angular.copy will do deep copy and Object.assign will not do it. Try in your example to run following code:

```
$scope.angularClone = angular.copy($scope.obj1);
$scope.angularClone.prop4.a = 5;
$scope.obj1.prop4.a; // Will return 1
```

and

```
$scope.es6clone = Object.assign({}, $scope.obj1) ;
$scope.es6clone.prop4.a = 4;
$scope.obj1.prop4.a; // Will return 4 because object assign doesn't create deep copy.
```