# Add object value instead of reference to the new variable in Type Script

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```js
saveOccuraces(currentFrequency: Frequencies) {
  var freq = new Frequencies();
  freq = currentFrequency;
  // freq.occurance = currentFrequency.occurance; // <--Problem is here
  this.selectedFrequencies.push(freq);
}
```

```html
<md-input-container>
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="currentFrequency.occurance" mdInput placeholder="Every" name="occurance">
</md-input-container>

<button md-icon-button (click)="saveOccuraces(currentFrequency)">
  <md-icon>add</md-icon>
</button>
```

In the above code if I execute as it is, all occurrence values are updating with new one, if i comment `freq=currentFrequency;` line and un comment `freq.occurance = currentFrequency.occurance;` then it is working fine.

Is there any alternative to push objects with value only (withou

Comment: what you mean (withou ??

Comment: you are talking about https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between angular.copy() and assignment (=)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749433/difference-between-angular-copy-and-assignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a constructor in `Frequencies` like below

```
Frequencies(frequencies:Frequencies){
this.occurance = frequencies.occurance;
}
```

Change the code like this

```
saveOccuraces(currentFrequency:Frequencies){
        var freq= new Frequencies(currentFrequency);
        this.selectedFrequencies.push(freq);
    }
```

Alternative Way using Object.Assign()

```
saveOccuraces(currentFrequency:Frequencies){
            var freq= Object.assign(new Frequencies(),currentFrequency);
            this.selectedFrequencies.push(freq);
        }
```